Capsule Network for Steganalysis (Binary Classification) Not Training
I am currently working on a steganalysis model using a capsule network. I used this implementation of CapsNet, which was based on Xifeng Guo's Keras code.
I replicated DRCaps, a CapsNet model used for COVID Diagnostics through X-ray Images to use due to following reasons:

Same size and type of input images (256 × 256 grayscale images).
The authors experimented with different hyperparameters configurations and their final DRCaps model achieved a high accuracy of 90.0%.
I figured the model's good performance would also translate to binary classification in steganalysis.

For your reference, here are the hyperparameters of the DRCaps model.
I have the same parameters for Input, Convolutional, and PrimaryCaps layers. For the ClassCaps layer, I changed the number of classes to 2 (cover/stego) instead of 3. My implementation of the model and its summary are shown below.
class PrimaryCaps(Layer):
    """A PrimaryCaps layer. It allows to move to capsule's domain, encapsulating scalars in vectors.

    Args:
        n_caps: The number of capsules in this layer.
        dims_caps: The dimension of the output vector of a capsule.
        kernel_size: Height and width of the 2D convolution window.
        strides: Strides of the convolution along the height and width.
        padding: Type of padding used in the convolution.
        activation: Activation function to use.
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        n_caps,
        dims_caps,
        kernel_size,
        strides,
        padding,
        activation=None,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        super(PrimaryCaps, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.n_caps = n_caps
        self.dims_caps = dims_caps
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.strides = strides
        self.padding = padding
        self.activation = activation

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config.update(
            {
                "n_caps": self.n_caps,
                "dims_caps": self.dims_caps,
                "kernel_size": self.kernel_size,
                "strides": self.strides,
                "padding": self.padding,
                "activation": self.activation,
            }
        )
        return config

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert (
            len(input_shape) >= 4
        ), "The input Tensor of a PrimaryCaps should have shape=[None, width, height, channels]"

        # Apply Convolution n_caps times
        self.conv2d = Conv2D(
            filters=self.n_caps * self.dims_caps,
            kernel_size=self.kernel_size,
            strides=self.strides,
            padding=self.padding,
            activation=self.activation,
            name="primarycaps_conv2d",
        )

        # Reshape the convolutional layer output
        feature_dims = int((input_shape[1] - self.kernel_size + 1) / self.strides)
        self.reshape = Reshape(
            (feature_dims ** 2 * self.n_caps, self.dims_caps),
            name="primarycaps_reshape",
        )

        # Squash the vectors output
        self.squash = Lambda(squash, name="primarycaps_squash")

        self.built = True

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.conv2d(inputs)
        x = self.reshape(x)
        return self.squash(x)


class DenseCaps(Layer):
    """A DenseCaps layer, where the dynamic routing algorithm is executed.

    Args:
        n_caps: The number of capsules in this layer.
        dims_caps: The dimension of the output vector of a capsule.
        r_iter: Number of routing iterations.
        kernel_initializer: Initializer that define the way to set the initial random weights.
        shared_weights: number of input capsules that must have the same weight.
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        n_caps,
        dims_caps,
        r_iter=3,
        kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=0.1),
        shared_weights=1,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        super(DenseCaps, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.n_caps = n_caps
        self.dims_caps = dims_caps
        self.r_iter = r_iter
        self.kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer
        self.shared_weights = shared_weights

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config.update(
            {
                "n_caps": self.n_caps,
                "dims_caps": self.dims_caps,
                "r_iter": self.r_iter,
                "kernel_initializer": self.kernel_initializer,
                "shared_weights": self.shared_weights,
            }
        )
        return config

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert (
            len(input_shape) == 3
        ), "The input Tensor of a DenseCaps should have shape=[None, input_n_caps, input_dims_caps]"

        self.input_n_caps = input_shape[1]
        self.input_dims_caps = input_shape[2]

        self.W = self.add_weight(
            name="W",
            shape=(
                1,
                self.input_n_caps // self.shared_weights,
                self.n_caps,
                self.dims_caps,
                self.input_dims_caps,
            ),
            initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
        )

        self.built = True

    def call(self, inputs):
        # Calculate predictions
        # Note: Matmul doesn't care about batch_size (it just uses the same self.W multiple times)
        inputs = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(inputs, -1), 2)
        W_tiled = tf.tile(self.W, [1, self.shared_weights, 1, 1, 1])
        predictions = tf.matmul(W_tiled, inputs)

        # === DYNAMIC ROUTING ===
        raw_weights = tf.zeros([1, self.input_n_caps, self.n_caps, 1, 1])

        for i in range(self.r_iter):
            # Line 4, computes Eq.(3)
            routing_weights = tf.nn.softmax(raw_weights, axis=2)

            # Line 5
            outputs = tf.reduce_sum(
                routing_weights * predictions, axis=1, keepdims=True
            )

            # Line 6
            outputs = squash(outputs, axis=-2)

            # Line 7
            if i < self.r_iter - 1:
                outputs_tiled = tf.tile(outputs, [1, self.input_n_caps, 1, 1, 1])
                raw_weights += tf.matmul(predictions, outputs_tiled, transpose_a=True)

        return tf.squeeze(outputs, axis=[1, -1]), routing_weights


def mask(inputs):
    """Mask a Tensor with shape (batch_size, n_capsules, dim_vector).

    It can be done either by selecting the capsule with max length or by an additional input mask.
    The first is usually the method for testing, the second is the one for the training.

    Args:
        inputs: Either a tensor to be masked (output of the class capsules)
                or a tensor with both the tensor and an additional input mask
    """
    # Mask provided?
    if type(inputs) is tuple or type(inputs) is list:
        inputs, mask = inputs[0], inputs[1]
    else:
        # Calculate the mask by the max length of capsules.
        x = compute_vectors_length(inputs)
        # Generate one-hot encoded mask
        mask = one_hot(indices=argmax(x, 1), num_classes=x.get_shape().as_list()[-1])

    # Mask the inputs
    masked = batch_flatten(inputs * expand_dims(mask, -1))
    return masked


def compute_vectors_length(vecs, axis=-1):
    """Compute vectors' length. This is used to compute final prediction as probabilities.

    Args:
        vecs: A tensor with shape (batch_size, n_vectors, dim_vector)

    Returns:
        A new tensor with shape (batch_size, n_vectors)
    """
    return tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(vecs), axis) + epsilon())


def squash(vectors, axis=-1):
    """The non-linear activation used in Capsule, computes Eq.(1)

    It drives the length of a large vector to near 1 and small vector to 0.

    Args:
        vectors: The vectors to be squashed, N-dim tensor.
        axis: The axis to squash.
    Returns:
        A tensor with the same shape as input vectors, but squashed in 'vec_len' dimension.
    """
    s_squared_norm = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(vectors), axis, keepdims=True)
    scale = s_squared_norm / (1 + s_squared_norm) / tf.sqrt(s_squared_norm + epsilon())
    return scale * vectors

def DRCaps(input_shape, n_class, name="CapsuleNetwork"):
    """Capsule Network model implementation, used for MNIST dataset training.

    The model has been adapted from
    the [official paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.09829).

    Arguments:
        input_shape: 3-Dimensional data shape (width, height, channels).
        n_class: Number of classes.
    """
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
    
    # --- Encoder ---
    # Input
    x = Input(shape=input_shape)

    # Layer 1
    conv1 = Conv2D(
        filters=128,
        kernel_size=(3,3),
        strides=1,
        padding="valid",
        dilation_rate=(8,8),
        activation="relu",
        name="conv1",
    )(x)

    # Layer 2
    conv2 = Conv2D(
        filters=64,
        kernel_size=(3,3),
        strides=2,
        padding="valid",
        dilation_rate=(1,1),
        activation="relu",
        name="conv2",
    )(conv1)

    # Layer 3
    conv3 = Conv2D(
        filters=128,
        kernel_size=(3,3),
        strides=1,
        padding="valid",
        dilation_rate=(4,4),
        activation="relu",
        name="conv3",
    )(conv2)

    # Layer 4
    conv4 = Conv2D(
        filters=64,
        kernel_size=(3,3),
        strides=2,
        padding="valid",
        dilation_rate=(1,1),
        activation="relu",
        name="conv4",
    )(conv3)

    # Layer 5
    conv5 = Conv2D(
        filters=64,
        kernel_size=(3,3),
        strides=1,
        padding="valid",
        dilation_rate=(2,2),
        activation="relu",
        name="conv5",
    )(conv4)

    # Layer 6
    conv6 = Conv2D(
        filters=64,
        kernel_size=(3,3),
        strides=2,
        padding="valid",
        dilation_rate=(1,1),
        activation="relu",
        name="conv6",
    )(conv5)

    # Layer 7
    conv7 = Conv2D(
        filters=64,
        kernel_size=(3,3),
        strides=2,
        padding="valid",
        dilation_rate=(1,1),
        activation="relu",
        name="conv7",
    )(conv6)
    
    # Layer 8: PrimaryCaps Layer
    primary_caps = PrimaryCaps(
        n_caps=32,
        dims_caps=8,
        kernel_size=9,
        strides=2,
        padding="valid",
        activation="relu",
        name="primary_caps",
    )(conv7)

    # Layer 9: ClassCaps Layer: since routing it is computed only
    # between two consecutive capsule layers, it only happens here
    class_caps = DenseCaps(n_caps=n_class, dims_caps=16, name="digit_caps")(
        primary_caps
    )[0]

    # Layer 4: A convenience layer to calculate vectors' length
    vec_len = Lambda(compute_vectors_length, name="vec_len")(class_caps)

    # --- Decoder ---
    y = Input(shape=(n_class,))
    
    # Layer 10: A convenience layer to compute the masked capsules' output
    masked = Lambda(mask, name="masked")(
        class_caps
    )  # Mask using the capsule with maximal length. For prediction
    masked_by_y = Lambda(mask, name="masked_by_y")(
        [class_caps, y]
    )  # The true label is used to mask the output of capsule layer. For training

    # Layer 11-14: Four Dense layer for the image reconstruction
    decoder = Sequential(name="decoder")
    decoder.add(Dense(64, activation="relu", input_dim=16 * n_class, name="dense_1"))
    decoder.add(Dense(128, activation="relu", name="dense_2"))
    decoder.add(Dense(128, activation="relu", name="dense_3"))
    decoder.add(
        Dense(tf.math.reduce_prod(input_shape), activation="sigmoid", name="dense_4")
    )

    # Layer 15: Reshape the output as the image provided in input
    decoder.add(Reshape(target_shape=input_shape, name="img_reconstructed"))

    # Models for training and evaluation (prediction)
    train_model = Model(
        inputs=[x, y], outputs=[vec_len, decoder(masked_by_y)], name=name
    )
    eval_model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=[vec_len, decoder(masked)], name=name)

    return train_model, eval_model

model_params = {
    "input_shape": X_train.shape[1:],
    "n_class": y_train.shape[1],
    "name": "model_DRCaps_S_UNIWARD_04bpp",
}

model, eval_model = DRCaps(**model_params)
model.summary()

Model: "model_DRCaps_S_UNIWARD_04bpp"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 256, 256, 1) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1 (Conv2D)                  (None, 240, 240, 128 1280        input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2 (Conv2D)                  (None, 119, 119, 64) 73792       conv1[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3 (Conv2D)                  (None, 111, 111, 128 73856       conv2[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv4 (Conv2D)                  (None, 55, 55, 64)   73792       conv3[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5 (Conv2D)                  (None, 51, 51, 64)   36928       conv4[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv6 (Conv2D)                  (None, 25, 25, 64)   36928       conv5[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv7 (Conv2D)                  (None, 12, 12, 64)   36928       conv6[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
primary_caps (PrimaryCaps)      (None, 128, 8)       1327360     conv7[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
digit_caps (DenseCaps)          ((None, 2, 16), (Non 32768       primary_caps[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, 2)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
masked_by_y (Lambda)            (None, None)         0           digit_caps[0][0]                 
                                                                 input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
vec_len (Lambda)                (None, 2)            0           digit_caps[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
decoder (Sequential)            (None, 256, 256, 1)  8481088     masked_by_y[0][0]                
==================================================================================================
Total params: 10,174,720
Trainable params: 10,174,720
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________

After replicating the model, I proceeded with the training using the hyperparameters of the DRCaps model: λ recon = 32.768, a batch size equal to 32, and the Adam optimizer with the default parameters: a learning rate, lr = 0.001, and a lr decay = 0.9.
The training function is a revision of the training function found in this repository of GBRAS-Net, a steganalysis model based on CNN.
def train(model, X_train, y_train, X_valid, y_valid, X_test, y_test, batch_size=32, epochs=50, lr=0.001, lr_decay_mul=0.9, lam_recon=32.768):
    """Train a given Capsule Network model.

    Args:
        model: The CapsuleNet model to train.
        data: The dataset that you want to train: ((x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)).
        epochs: Number of epochs for the training.
        batch_size: Size of the batch used for the training.
        lr: Initial learning rate value.
        lr_decay_mul: The value multiplied by lr at each epoch. Set a larger value for larger epochs.
        lam_recon: The coefficient for the loss of decoder (if present).
    Returns:
        The trained model.
    """
    # Compile the model
    model.compile(
        optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=lr),
        loss=[margin_loss, "mse"],
        loss_weights=[1.0, lam_recon],
        metrics=["accuracy"],
    )
        
    start_time = tm.time()
    log_dir=path_log_base+"/"+model.name+"_"+str(datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()[:19].replace("T", "_").replace(":","-"))
    tensorboard = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir, histogram_freq=1)
    filepath = log_dir+"/saved-model-{epoch:03d}-{val_vec_len_accuracy:.4f}-{val_decoder_accuracy:.4f}.hdf5"
    checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor=['val_vec_len_accuracy', 'val_decoder_accuracy'], save_best_only=False, mode='max')
    # Define a callback to reduce learning rate
    lrcb = callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(
            schedule=lambda epoch: lr * (lr_decay_mul ** epoch)
        )
    # Define a callback to save the weights of the model
    weights_dir = os.path.join(log_dir, 'weights')
    os.makedirs(weights_dir)
    weights_filepath = weights_dir+"/saved-weights-{epoch:03d}.hdf5"
    weights_checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(weights_filepath, monitor=['val_vec_len_accuracy', 'val_decoder_accuracy'], save_best_only=False, save_weights_only=True, mode='max')
    model.reset_states()
    
    global lossTEST
    global vec_len_lossTEST
    global decoder_lossTEST
    global vec_len_accuracyTEST
    global decoder_accuracyTEST
    global lossTRAIN
    global vec_len_lossTRAIN
    global decoder_lossTRAIN
    global vec_len_accuracyTRAIN
    global decoder_accuracyTRAIN
    global lossVALID
    global vec_len_lossVALID
    global decoder_lossVALID
    global vec_len_accuracyVALID
    global decoder_accuracyVALID
    
    lossTEST, vec_len_lossTEST, decoder_lossTEST, vec_len_accuracyTEST, decoder_accuracyTEST = model.evaluate(x=(X_test, y_test), y=(y_test, X_test), verbose=None)
    lossTRAIN, vec_len_lossTRAIN, decoder_lossTRAIN, vec_len_accuracyTRAIN, decoder_accuracyTRAIN = model.evaluate(x=(X_train, y_train), y=(y_train, X_train),verbose=None)
    lossVALID, vec_len_lossVALID, decoder_lossVALID, vec_len_accuracyVALID, decoder_accuracyVALID = model.evaluate(x=(X_valid, y_valid), y=(y_valid, X_valid),verbose=None)

    global history
    global model_Name
    global log_Dir
    global weights_Dir
    model_Name = model.name
    log_Dir = log_dir
    weights_Dir = weights_dir
    print("Starting the training...")
    history=model.fit(
        x=(X_train, y_train),
        y=(y_train, X_train),
        epochs=epochs,
        callbacks=[tensorboard,checkpoint,lrcb,weights_checkpoint],
        batch_size=batch_size,
        validation_data=((X_valid, y_valid), (y_valid, X_valid)),
        verbose=2
    )
    
    metrics = model.evaluate(x=(X_test, y_test), y=(y_test, X_test), verbose=0)
     
    TIME = tm.time() - start_time
    print("Time "+model.name+" = %s [seconds]" % TIME)
    
    print("\n")
    print(log_dir)
    print(weights_dir)
    return {k:v for k,v in zip (model.metrics_names, metrics)}

train(model, X_train, y_train, X_valid, y_valid, X_test, y_test, batch_size=32, epochs=100, lr=0.001, lr_decay_mul=0.9, lam_recon=32.768)

Starting the training...
Epoch 1/100
250/250 - 1105s - loss: 434062.7500 - vec_len_loss: 0.3945 - decoder_loss: 13246.5352 - vec_len_accuracy: 0.4999 - decoder_accuracy: 0.0018 - val_loss: 297717.2188 - val_vec_len_loss: 0.3952 - val_decoder_loss: 9085.5957 - val_vec_len_accuracy: 0.5000 - val_decoder_accuracy: 0.0055 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 2/100
250/250 - 1104s - loss: 433786.9062 - vec_len_loss: 0.2633 - decoder_loss: 13238.1162 - vec_len_accuracy: 0.5013 - decoder_accuracy: 0.0018 - val_loss: 297716.8750 - val_vec_len_loss: 0.2208 - val_decoder_loss: 9085.5918 - val_vec_len_accuracy: 0.5000 - val_decoder_accuracy: 0.0055 - lr: 9.0000e-04
Epoch 3/100
250/250 - 1103s - loss: 433786.7500 - vec_len_loss: 0.2182 - decoder_loss: 13238.1152 - vec_len_accuracy: 0.4946 - decoder_accuracy: 0.0018 - val_loss: 297716.8438 - val_vec_len_loss: 0.2150 - val_decoder_loss: 9085.5928 - val_vec_len_accuracy: 0.5000 - val_decoder_accuracy: 0.0055 - lr: 8.1000e-04
Epoch 4/100
250/250 - 1102s - loss: 433786.7500 - vec_len_loss: 0.2152 - decoder_loss: 13238.1143 - vec_len_accuracy: 0.5036 - decoder_accuracy: 0.0018 - val_loss: 297716.8750 - val_vec_len_loss: 0.2143 - val_decoder_loss: 9085.5918 - val_vec_len_accuracy: 0.5000 - val_decoder_accuracy: 0.0055 - lr: 7.2900e-04
Epoch 5/100
250/250 - 1100s - loss: 433786.5938 - vec_len_loss: 0.2149 - decoder_loss: 13238.1094 - vec_len_accuracy: 0.5056 - decoder_accuracy: 0.0018 - val_loss: 297716.8750 - val_vec_len_loss: 0.2138 - val_decoder_loss: 9085.5918 - val_vec_len_accuracy: 0.5000 - val_decoder_accuracy: 0.0055 - lr: 6.5610e-04
Epoch 6/100
250/250 - 1100s - loss: 433786.7188 - vec_len_loss: 0.2147 - decoder_loss: 13238.1123 - vec_len_accuracy: 0.4988 - decoder_accuracy: 0.0018 - val_loss: 297716.8750 - val_vec_len_loss: 0.2212 - val_decoder_loss: 9085.5918 - val_vec_len_accuracy: 0.5000 - val_decoder_accuracy: 0.0055 - lr: 5.9049e-04
Epoch 7/100
250/250 - 1100s - loss: 433786.5625 - vec_len_loss: 0.2146 - decoder_loss: 13238.1055 - vec_len_accuracy: 0.4915 - decoder_accuracy: 0.0018 - val_loss: 297716.8750 - val_vec_len_loss: 0.2146 - val_decoder_loss: 9085.5918 - val_vec_len_accuracy: 0.5000 - val_decoder_accuracy: 0.0055 - lr: 5.3144e-04
Epoch 8/100
250/250 - 1100s - loss: 433786.6562 - vec_len_loss: 0.2145 - decoder_loss: 13238.1143 - vec_len_accuracy: 0.5064 - decoder_accuracy: 0.0018 - val_loss: 297716.8438 - val_vec_len_loss: 0.2135 - val_decoder_loss: 9085.5918 - val_vec_len_accuracy: 0.5000 - val_decoder_accuracy: 0.0055 - lr: 4.7830e-04
Epoch 9/100
250/250 - 1101s - loss: 433786.5000 - vec_len_loss: 0.2141 - decoder_loss: 13238.1064 - vec_len_accuracy: 0.4991 - decoder_accuracy: 0.0018 - val_loss: 297716.8750 - val_vec_len_loss: 0.2143 - val_decoder_loss: 9085.5918 - val_vec_len_accuracy: 0.5000 - val_decoder_accuracy: 0.0055 - lr: 4.3047e-04
Epoch 10/100
250/250 - 1102s - loss: 433786.5625 - vec_len_loss: 0.2145 - decoder_loss: 13238.1064 - vec_len_accuracy: 0.4969 - decoder_accuracy: 0.0018 - val_loss: 297716.8438 - val_vec_len_loss: 0.2135 - val_decoder_loss: 9085.5918 - val_vec_len_accuracy: 0.5000 - val_decoder_accuracy: 0.0055 - lr: 3.8742e-04
Epoch 11/100
250/250 - 1104s - loss: 433786.5938 - vec_len_loss: 0.2142 - decoder_loss: 13238.1152 - vec_len_accuracy: 0.4906 - decoder_accuracy: 0.0018 - val_loss: 297716.8438 - val_vec_len_loss: 0.2135 - val_decoder_loss: 9085.5918 - val_vec_len_accuracy: 0.5000 - val_decoder_accuracy: 0.0055 - lr: 3.4868e-04
Epoch 12/100
250/250 - 1114s - loss: 433786.5625 - vec_len_loss: 0.2142 - decoder_loss: 13238.1123 - vec_len_accuracy: 0.4956 - decoder_accuracy: 0.0018 - val_loss: 297716.8750 - val_vec_len_loss: 0.2141 - val_decoder_loss: 9085.5918 - val_vec_len_accuracy: 0.5000 - val_decoder_accuracy: 0.0055 - lr: 3.1381e-04
Epoch 13/100
250/250 - 1115s - loss: 433786.5625 - vec_len_loss: 0.2138 - decoder_loss: 13238.1113 - vec_len_accuracy: 0.4996 - decoder_accuracy: 0.0018 - val_loss: 297716.8750 - val_vec_len_loss: 0.2146 - val_decoder_loss: 9085.5918 - val_vec_len_accuracy: 0.5000 - val_decoder_accuracy: 0.0055 - lr: 2.8243e-04
Epoch 14/100
250/250 - 1115s - loss: 433786.5625 - vec_len_loss: 0.2142 - decoder_loss: 13238.1113 - vec_len_accuracy: 0.4940 - decoder_accuracy: 0.0018 - val_loss: 297716.8750 - val_vec_len_loss: 0.2142 - val_decoder_loss: 9085.5918 - val_vec_len_accuracy: 0.5000 - val_decoder_accuracy: 0.0055 - lr: 2.5419e-04
Epoch 15/100
250/250 - 1114s - loss: 433786.6562 - vec_len_loss: 0.2140 - decoder_loss: 13238.1094 - vec_len_accuracy: 0.4855 - decoder_accuracy: 0.0018 - val_loss: 297716.8750 - val_vec_len_loss: 0.2133 - val_decoder_loss: 9085.5918 - val_vec_len_accuracy: 0.5000 - val_decoder_accuracy: 0.0055 - lr: 2.2877e-04
Epoch 16/100
250/250 - 1114s - loss: 433786.6250 - vec_len_loss: 0.2140 - decoder_loss: 13238.1113 - vec_len_accuracy: 0.4985 - decoder_accuracy: 0.0018 - val_loss: 297716.8750 - val_vec_len_loss: 0.2137 - val_decoder_loss: 9085.5918 - val_vec_len_accuracy: 0.5000 - val_decoder_accuracy: 0.0055 - lr: 2.0589e-04
Epoch 17/100
250/250 - 1115s - loss: 433786.4688 - vec_len_loss: 0.2138 - decoder_loss: 13238.1074 - vec_len_accuracy: 0.4939 - decoder_accuracy: 0.0018 - val_loss: 297716.8438 - val_vec_len_loss: 0.2135 - val_decoder_loss: 9085.5918 - val_vec_len_accuracy: 0.5000 - val_decoder_accuracy: 0.0055 - lr: 1.8530e-04
Epoch 18/100
250/250 - 1116s - loss: 433786.5312 - vec_len_loss: 0.2135 - decoder_loss: 13238.1113 - vec_len_accuracy: 0.5045 - decoder_accuracy: 0.0018 - val_loss: 297716.8750 - val_vec_len_loss: 0.2136 - val_decoder_loss: 9085.5918 - val_vec_len_accuracy: 0.5000 - val_decoder_accuracy: 0.0055 - lr: 1.6677e-04
Epoch 19/100
250/250 - 1118s - loss: 433786.6250 - vec_len_loss: 0.2140 - decoder_loss: 13238.1201 - vec_len_accuracy: 0.4976 - decoder_accuracy: 0.0018 - val_loss: 297716.8750 - val_vec_len_loss: 0.2137 - val_decoder_loss: 9085.5918 - val_vec_len_accuracy: 0.5000 - val_decoder_accuracy: 0.0055 - lr: 1.5009e-04
Epoch 20/100
250/250 - 1118s - loss: 433786.6875 - vec_len_loss: 0.2139 - decoder_loss: 13238.1113 - vec_len_accuracy: 0.4969 - decoder_accuracy: 0.0018 - val_loss: 297716.8750 - val_vec_len_loss: 0.2139 - val_decoder_loss: 9085.5918 - val_vec_len_accuracy: 0.5000 - val_decoder_accuracy: 0.0055 - lr: 1.3509e-04

For the DRCaps model, the authors observed that only 20 epochs are enough to obtain a good performance. However, mine's accuracy and loss did not change. The decoder loss also seems unusually high compared to the vector length loss, which makes me believe something is wrong with my implementation.
In addition, the images I used are the same as GBRAS-Net's. I also trained GBRAS-Net myself and I was able to reproduce their results.
Any input is greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Unfortunately, it's unlikely you will get an answer here. This is a TON of code with no further indication of where the issue(s) might be. You will need to do some debugging to isolate the issue and pose a more specific question (and may just find the issue yourself during that process).
